# Как перемножить два числа из кортежа?

Tags: python

У меня есть кортеж (1, 10) и мне требуется перемножить эти два числа из кортежа, как это сделать?

Comment: `test = (1, 10);print(test[0]*test[1])`, что не так?

Comment: @SKIP, А если чисел много? Универсальнее будет `print (reduce(lambda x, y: y * x, test))`.

Comment: Ну если с читерством в виде импортированных библиотек, то можно уж через `import numpy numpy.prod((1,10))`

Comment: [math.prod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.prod).

Answer (score 2):

```
x = (1,10)
res = 0
for i in x:
    if res == 0:
        res+=i
    else: 
        res = res*i
print(res)
```

Это будет работать как с большим кортежем, так и с вашим. Либо как написали в комментах используйте библиотеку numpy

Answer (score 2):

```
tup=(1,2,3,4,5,6)
r=1
for x in tup: r*=x
print(r)
```

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно умножить два элемента в кортеже, то Вы можете использовать:

```
> print((lambda x,y: x*y)(2,10))
```

Eсли жe Вам нужно перемножить n-элементов кортежа или списка,
то следует использовать функцию reduce,
например:

```
> from functools import reduce
> print((reduce(lambda x,y: x*y, (10,2,3,5))))
```

[Вот Вам дока](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html)

Так же варианты:

```
>  print([a[i]*a[i+1] for i in range(1)][0])
```

---

```
>  a,b = (1,10)
>  print(a*b)
```

---

#можно использовать с любым количеством вложенных в список кортежей

```
>  for i,j in [(10, 2)]:     
>      print(i*j)
```

---

#похожая конструкция для одного кортежа

```
>  mult = 1 
>  for i in (2,10):
>      mult *=i
>  print('rez', mult)
```